# How to mutate with useMutation from Apollo

Tags: reactjs, apollo, mutation

I have a `graphQL` query that give me all inputs to display in a form, and I have to use the same query to mutate database when there is an `onChange` event on an input.

I managed to make the query, and to display all my inputs.

Now, i'm having difficulties to find how I can resend my query with new value when a data is entered.

I need to send the specific `id` to make my backend understand that it has to mutate the existing article instead of creating a new one.

Any idea how to do this ?

Here is my `form.service.tsx`:

```
export const FORM = gql`
  mutation form($article: ArticleInput!) {
    form(annonce: $annonce) {
      article{
        id
      }
      formContent
    }
  }
`;

export const FormData = ({ children }) => {
  const [form, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(
    form,
    {
      variables: {
        annonce: {
          idtype: 2,
          id: 0, // I need this to be dynamic
        },
      },
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    form().then((res) => {
      if (res.data) {
        res.data.form.formContent = JSON.parse(
          res.data.form.formContent,
        );
      }
    });
  }, [form]);

  return children(data, loading, error);
};
```

Then I use this as a wrapper in `form.tsx` :

```
<FormData>
      {(data, loading) => {
        if (loading) return <>loading...</>;

        return (
          <>
            <Section3 dataToDisplay={data.groups} />
```

And finaly, in `section3.tsx` of my form :

```
const Section3 = ({ data }) => {
  const [typeDeBienSelected, setTypeDeBienSelected] = useState<Group>(
    data.find((item) => item.selected) ?? data[0],
  );

  return (
    <div className="hk-flex hk-flex-col hk-gap-8">
      <MyInputComponent
        list={typeDeBien ?? []}
        value={typeDeBienSelected}
        setValue={(e) => setTypeDeBienSelected(e)}
      />
  );
};

export default Section3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to dynamically send the ID for mutation when an input value changes.
Here is the steps you can follow to achieve this.

#### Add State Variable in FormData Component

In your `FormData` component, let's add a s state variable to track the `id` value and pass the `setId` function as a prop from FormData to `Section3.tsx` component.

```
export const FormData = ({ children }) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(0); // State variable to track the ID

  const [form, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(
    FORM,
    {
      variables: {
        annonce: {
          idtype: 2,
          id: id, // Use the dynamic ID here
        },
      },
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    form().then((res) => {
      if (res.data) {
        res.data.form.formContent = JSON.parse(
          res.data.form.formContent,
        );
      }
    });
  }, [form]);

  return children(data, loading, error, setId); // Pass the setId function as a prop
};
```

#### Update setValue function in Section3 Component

In the `Section3.tsx`, update the `setValue` function to call the `setId` function and pass the new `ID`:

```
const Section3 = ({ data, setId }) => {
  const [typeDeBienSelected, setTypeDeBienSelected] = useState(
    data.find((item) => item.selected) ?? data[0],
  );

  const handleInputChange = (newValue) => {
    setTypeDeBienSelected(newValue);
    setId(newValue.id); // Update the ID when the input value changes
  };

  return (
    <div className="hk-flex hk-flex-col hk-gap-8">
      <MyInputComponent
        list={typeDeBien ?? []}
        value={typeDeBienSelected}
        setValue={handleInputChange} // Pass the updated function here
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Section3;
```

Comment: I followed your logic, just used an atom from Jotai instead and it's fine. Thank you !